# Trouble getting partitions to make a difference in query time

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I'm just experimenting a bit with partitions with some dummy data, and am not having any luck optimizing my queries so far.

I downloaded a dataset from the Internet, which consists of a single table of `measurements`:

```
CREATE TABLE `partitioned_measures` (
  `measure_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `station_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wind_mtsperhour` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `windgust_mtsperhour` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `windangle` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `rain_mm` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temperature_dht11` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `humidity_dht11` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `barometric_pressure` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `barometric_temperature` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `lux` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_plugged` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `battery_level` int(3) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(measure_timestamp))
(PARTITION `slow` VALUES LESS THAN (736634) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `fast` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

*Just as a learning exercise* I wanted to try to partition the measurements by `measure_timestamp` (without help of indexing). Specifically, I thought it would be interesting to try and put the most recent month in a partition by itself. (I understand that it's best to have equally-sized partitions, but I just wanted to experiment)

I used the following command to add the partition (Note that the dataset ends in Dec of 2016, and the vast majority of the datapoints are in prior months):

```
ALTER TABLE partitioned_measures 
    PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(measure_timestamp)) (
        PARTITION slow VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DAYS('2016-12-01')), 
        PARTITION fast VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    );
```

To query, I'm looking at all entries from the 2nd and onward (just to be sure that I'm only looking in the latest partition):

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM partitioned_measures 
    WHERE measure_timestamp >= '2016-12-02' 
    AND DAYOFWEEK(measure_timestamp) = 1;
```

When I add an EXPLAIN to the front of that, I get the following:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | partitioned_measures | slow,fast  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1835458 |    33.33 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

But the query time is about the same as it was before the partition (~1.6 seconds). I've never used partitions before so I feel like there's something conceptual that I'm missing.

Comment: How big is the data set? If data set is not that big runtime difference between partitioned table vs non partitioned table might not make a difference because the db engine needs some time for "overhead" i.e coming up with the query plan, executing it, returning results

Comment: @mdem7 There are 1,846,124 rows

Comment: And how much of those rows go into the fast partition? Did you make any indexes?

Comment: Your query performance is caused by DAYOFWEEK(measure_timestamp) = 1. The function on the column makes the query engine can't use index.

Comment: @PeterHe Well spotted, but what if `measure_timestamp` has a nice fast index? Wouldn't the query go for that first?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I actually removed the index because I wanted to see the performance just with the partitioning.

Comment: That was a bad idea... always have an index on your partitioning thingy.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware This is a learning experiment, so I don't think anything is a bad idea

Comment: OK, good point, but in practice you will always want to have an index there.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the index will be used for the first condition: measure_timestamp >= '2016-12-02' only, and can't be used for the DAYOFWEEK condition. If the first condition is really wide, performance will be bad.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Maybe a better way to phrase things is what is the point of partitioning if I need to index anyways? Like, partitioning is kindof a linear optimization as far as I can see, while indexing is logarithmic. So I'm not quite sure I see the benefit then

Comment: Well, you know that indexes speed things up, so they will also do that when you partition. When partitions are done right your query won't have to use all partitions (you know that, I know). An index also helps the query optimizer choose how to perform the query. See; [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: @PeterHe: Yes, if the query really needs both partitions, they won't help.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I guess that I'm questioning whether I'm even doing things correctly. I'm doubtful that my partitions are working as expected, since a few thousand rows (in the smaller partition) shouldn't take > 1 second to query.

Comment: I would suggestion to try to add the index and test it again with an without partitioning.

Comment: Simple guideline when you don't have atleast 1 million records in a table don't use partitions

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have > 1 million rows. When I use EXPLAIN though it looks like my query is hitting both partitions, when I only want it to hit the second one. (Also note that this is just an experiment..nothing going to production)

Comment: @RaymondNijland wheresmycookie has 1,846,124 records, and I don't think such a general rule is any good. It depends heavily on your data and query.

Comment: *" I don't think such a general rule is any good. It depends heavily on your data and query. "*  Well true @KIKOSoftware well it's a pretty safe guideline i did some testing on it, with differenct datasets ,record numbers, columns datatypes and columns numbers the sweet spot was atleast 1 million+ where i noticed partitions pay off performance wise.. And not to mention hardware.

Comment: topicstarter can you execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE partitioned_measures` and post that here? And also `EXPLAIN your_query`

Comment: @RaymondNijland so I do have a pretty large test dataset, but am not seeing those benefits. Also, when I use EXPLAIN to prefix my query, I'm seeing that it actually _does_ hit all of the partitions, even though I specify a date range that falls only in the last partition. That's what I'm really stuck on.

Comment: And the `SHOW CREATE TABLE partitioned_measures` ? we also ready need that infromation?

Comment: @RaymondNijland added, thanks

Comment: is it correct you are using MySQL 5.1? `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland 5.7.20

Comment: @PeterHe - No. `DAYOFWEEK` won't prevent `INDEX(measure_timestamp)` from being used for the other part of the `WHERE`.  The Optimizer will pick the part(s) of the `WHERE` it can use with an index, then filter on the other parts later.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - No.  It is usually redundant and wasteful to say `PARTITION BY RANGE(x)` with `INDEX(x)`.  OTOH, the example in the Question would benefit -- the index might avoid a full scan of the partition.  It is typical to put the partition key _last_ in some composite indexes.

Comment: @PeterHe - "If the first condition is really wide, performance will be bad" -- What do you mean by "wide".  If you mean the columns are wide, then I disagree.  The column width makes only a small difference.

Comment: @PeterHe - If the query needs both partitions, then it is _partitioning_ that it does not need.  Any indexes may still be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky but i found a working solution or should i say a workaround, it seams to be a MySQL bug?

```
   ALTER TABLE partitioned_measures 
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(measure_timestamp) (
        PARTITION slow VALUES LESS THAN('2016-12-01'), 
        PARTITION fast VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
    );
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ggxewQCBjxTFNSjXv4ZAXx/0) which does use Partition Pruning correctly

i noticed that syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html)

I still find it wierd the partioning puning does not work correct, with

```
    ALTER TABLE partitioned_measures 
    PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(measure_timestamp)) (
        PARTITION slow VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DAYS('2016-12-01')), 
        PARTITION fast VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    );
```

MySQL 5.7 should be able to do the Partition Pruning which `TO_DAYS()` just fine

> Pruning can also be applied for tables partitioned on a DATE or
>   DATETIME column when the partitioning expression uses the YEAR() or
>   TO_DAYS() function. In addition, in MySQL 5.7

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-pruning.html)

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWR7XdHaYRYDByxtSTiw6y/0) which does not use Partition Pruning correct, i've tryed [alot](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWR7XdHaYRYDByxtSTiw6y/2) to get it working all methods failed which i could think off.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation:

It *did* do the pruning you requested, but it added the *first* partition.  Why?  Because there is where bad dates are put.

The workaround is to have a bogus *first* partition:

```
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(measure_timestamp))
({ARTITION bogus  VALUES LESS THAN (0)      ENGINE = InnoDB,   -- any small value
 PARTITION `slow` VALUES LESS THAN (736634) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `fast` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Reference is buried in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-handling-nulls.html

If you had more than a trivial number of partitions you might have been more obvious that it picked the desired partition, plus always the first.

With rare [*exceptions*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint), partitioning does not provide better performance than you can get from a non-partitioned table with a suitable index.  In this case, `INDEX(measure_timestamp)`.  (Or a virtual column with `INDEX(dow, measure_timestamp)`.)